# Showing Visio 2007 grid on top of shapes?

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007, grid

Is it possible to display the grid in Visio 2007 on top of opaque shapes rather than beneath them?  For example, in the below screenshot, I'd like the grid to be visible even in the area of the white boxes in the lower-right corner.

[image: screenshot]

I know I can turn the fill off while working with the shapes and turn it back on later, but I am hoping not to have to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't possible but you can use guide points and guide lines for a similar purpose. These both show through opaque shapes.
To create a guider point drag the square in the corner of the two ruler bars onto the screen.
To create a guide line drag either ruler onto the screen.